# Programs started to fail suddenly with messages pertaining to shared memory

Tags: x11, ffmpeg, shared-memory

No idea why this is happening it's the first time I see this error. There seems to be enough space left in ram and drive.

First vnc fails now if I don't run it with -noshm option. Second one that fails is my screen grab inside ffmpeg. How can I prevent this from happening and how to fix it? Do I need to fully restart the server?

```
[x11grab @ 0x558615a2b220] Cannot get 1126032 bytes of shared memory: 
No space left on device. [x11grab @ 0x558615a2b220] Stream #0: not 
enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize

                total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   
 available
 Mem:           3762         662         547         967        2553        
 1898
 Swap:             0           0           0


Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           377M   39M  338M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       20G  5.3G   14G  28% /
tmpfs           1.9G   47M  1.8G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           377M   32K  377M   1% /run/user/116
tmpfs           377M  4.0K  377M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Output of ipcs command: https://gist.github.com/cAstraea/a204591c838f95c95d863ea04709ffa7

Comment: It's very interesting. What shows `ipcs` command.

Comment: Hmm it's a pretty long list what to look out for?  I posted it on an external link instead https://gist.github.com/cAstraea/a204591c838f95c95d863ea04709ffa7

Comment: I guess about this problem and post answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in huge count of **SystemV** Shared memory Segments. You need to delete it with `ipcrm` command. But before check **nattch** field, that shows number of programs that using this segment. For example:

Your fragment:

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 0          root       644        80         2                       
0x00000000 32769      root       644        16384      2                            
0x00000000 2065989638 ubuntu     777        1128032    0                       
0x00000000 1363181575 ubuntu     777        1126032    0
```

You can safely delete last 2 segments:

```
ipcrm --shmem-key 2065989638
ipcrm --shmem-key 1363181575
```

Comment: Yea thanks, cleared a few with ipcrm -m key and it restarted eventually. I think some of the cron scripts are leaving stuff behind and every time they're running they're making new segments.

Comment: Some buggy software leave this segments. Normally, the program that created segments must remove it. But it can leaves their in 2 reasons: 1. Program exited abnormally; 2. Worse programming style of programmer who use it.